# Kibana exact query cannot match content mix with character and number

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, syntax, kibana, kibana-4

My message field has sample content:

```
25/Sep/2015:23:01:05 +0800 | GET /activity/list?token=816bde08bd1e4da6&guid=5BCF14-B9DE HTTP/1.1 | 200 | 2537
```

And my elasticsearch index mapping

```
"message": {
    "norms": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to search using keyword `"816bde08bd1e4da6"` (quote included), but it didn't match. However, if I used `"816"` or `"bde"`, it shows up.

Should I change the mapping or should I use the other way of search syntax?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried to query es directly using @Val's suggestion:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?q=816bde08bd1e4da6'
```

It returns the correct result.

Then I used chrome dev-tool and found the following kibana query:

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "\"816bde08bd1e4da6\"",
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then it returns nothing.

Comment: What happens if you try to query ES directly without going through Kibana with `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?q=816bde08bd1e4da6'`? (make sure to replace `your_index` and `your_type` with the respective index and type names)

Comment: @Val I've update my description with the result. ES return correct result.

Comment: Are you sure you're pasting the right value in Kibana? I'm not sure where the suffix `...a161e83ed52ab6c3` comes from...

Comment: @Val I'm sorry that I've made some modification in the sample since the token is valid in a production environment.

Comment: What do you input **exactly** in the Kibana search field? It looks like it is `"816bde08bd1e4da6"`, correct? if yes, have you tried without double quotes?

Comment: Yes, I input `"816bde08bd1e4da6"`. If i search with `816bde08bd1e4da6`, many irrelevance data will show up, such as `da12c2758e4dc880e80601e6` will be matched.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze?field=message&pretty' -d '25/Sep/2015:23:01:05 +0800 | GET /activity/list?token=816bde08bd1e4da6&guid=5BCF14-B9DE HTTP/1.1 | 200 | 2537'`?